# optimize adding number to queue for median from stream of numbers

Tags: java, priority-queue, median

I was recently asked this question in an interview to find the median from data stream of numbers and I was able to come up with `Priority Queue` solution as shown below:

```
public class MedianFinder {
  private final PriorityQueue<Long> min = new PriorityQueue<>();
  private final PriorityQueue<Long> max = new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());

  public void addNum(long num) {
    max.offer(num);
    min.offer(max.poll());
    if (max.size() < min.size()) {
      max.offer(min.poll());
    }
  }

  public double findMedian() {
    if (max.size() == min.size())
      return (max.peek() + min.peek()) / 2.0;
    else
      return max.peek();
  }
}
```

Now interviewer wanted me to optimize `addNum` method because it has lot of O(log n) operations (around 5) and he wanted to see if we can optimize it any further so that we have fewer O(log n) operations? Is there anything we can do here to optimize `addNum` method?

Comment: Please note that by definition a fixed number C of  O(f(n)) is still in O(f(n) .O(f(n)*C)~>O(f(n). Having 5, 2 or 100 O(n log n) doesn't change the big O complexity. After all l, you don't know exactly how many constant log n operations are in the heap, for example

Answer (score 2):

This can reduce the average number of `offer` call from 2.5 to 1.5 and `poll` call from 1.5 to 0.5. Overall reduce the average number of O(log n) operations from 4 to 2.

```
public void addNum(long num) {
    if(!max.isEmpty() )
    {
        if(max.size() == min.size())
        {
            if(num > max.peek())
            {
                min.offer(num);
                max.offer(min.poll());
            }
            else
            {
                max.offer(num);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(num > max.peek())
            {
                min.offer(num);
            }
            else
            {
                max.offer(num);
                min.offer(max.poll());
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        max.offer(num);
    }
}
```

A more compact version (same logic)

```
public void addNum(long num) {
    if(!max.isEmpty())
    {
        (num > max.peek() ? min : max).offer(num);
        if(min.size() > max.size())
        {
            max.offer(min.poll());
        }
        else if(max.size() - min.size() > 1)
        {
            min.offer(max.poll());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        max.offer(num);
    }
}
```